# Multiple URL Received for a single NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection to communicate and pass/get datas to server. I am sending the request only once but server's access log shows that it is receiving multiple requests.I tried to log the request which i am sending to server but it is printing only once. The code to send request to server is :

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/services/OtherProcess/Status",serverIP]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSLog(@"Sending URL -> %@",url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    if(connection)
        [connection cancel];
    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

I even tried to add breakpoint and found it is called only once. Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I called a webpage with an iFrame. This iFrame also called the NSURLConnetion delegates.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate.  How can i use iFrame with NSURL connection for a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the delegate to log the connection `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`? 
The connection can stay active for a period of time redirecting and such which can cause your server to log multiple requests. You can use this method `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` to see if a redirect took place.

Redirects can happen if auth is needed. Also, if not sure, you can always test (only for testing since they will block your main thread) with a synchronous request using this method `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`

Comment: I am using the NSURLConnections delegates, but it also logs once in finishLoading.There is also no redirection happening, anyway ill check it once again. Is there a possibility that multiple open tcp connections to the same address might result in such a problem ? All the multiple logs are printed instantly in access logs.

Comment: every time you init a connection it will do a tcp request to your endpoint.

Comment: Will the connection close automatically on a success ??

Comment: Last time I checked, the connection leaves a socket open for a small amount of time (I think 12s?) so it can reuse the same connection. Now, every time you create a new connection, only that one should send the request. Also, `[connection cancel]` doesn't have much effect since the delegates remain active.

Comment: What exactly should i do to prevent it. Am i creating multiple connections or is it some kind of network problem.

Comment: I will try commenting out/deleting the `cancel` line and continue to log on the delegate functions. Canceling a connection only stops the calls to the delegates, the connection can still remain open. That way you may be able to tell if there is a redirect or retry. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944527/nsurlconnection-retry-on-401-status) and if all else fails use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the socket timeout in our server. Our server was closing the socket and iOS internally was retying 3 more times before it gives up. Increasing the timeout/changing the setting worked for me.